# How do I create an address in Ontology

Tags: javascript, node.js, ontology-network

What's the best way to create an address in Ontology using Javascript?

I can see how to call `getBalance` and `getTransactions` but need to get an address first.

Comment: Instead of asking the solution from here better you can google it. You'll get more solutions.

Comment: Already Googled it.

Comment: @Rudrika check out my answer below. I'm a contributor to Ontology so I can help out with any questions you have. I'd head over to the Ontology discord for more questions - they'll probably lock this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Ontology wallet with the Ontology TS SDK.

Install it with yarn or npm:

```
npm install 'ontology-ts-sdk' --save
```

And use with the following:

```
const Ont = require('ontology-ts-sdk');

const {
  Crypto,
  Account,
} = Ont;

const {
  PrivateKey,
} = Crypto;

const {
  Account,
} = Account;

const privateKey = PrivateKey.random();
const account = Account.create(privateKey, '123456', 'mickey');
console.log('Address: ' + account.address.toBase58());
```

Source: [Ontology Typescript SDK](https://github.com/ontio/ontology-ts-sdk/blob/3397c1f66ae66d0e0e2dfdc8dc4ce7caef3c479f/test/account.test.ts#L46)

Comment: Ok. I've previously created Address on OWallet using Password and Label.

Comment: Remove this part: ```const { Account, } = Account``` or you will receive an error